# Ubuntu 20.04 WiFi enters "Hardware Airplane Mode" after suspend resume

Tags: drivers, wireless, suspend, 20.04, iwlwifi

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10 on laptop with Intel i5-1035G4 and Intel AX201 WiFi card. Usually, when I power on the laptop, Wifi works fine. If I close the lid, then open it, the Wifi is always in "Hardware Airplane Mode" and there is no way to turn WiFi on again without shutting down and re-starting (the key with the Airplane on it does nothing). But even that does not work sometimes as after restart, the WiFi may be completely gone including the interface "wlan0" and does not appear in the settings applet. Just POOF! Gone :-(

Comment: As a workaround, try running:  `sudo rmmod iwldvm iwlwifi; sudo modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi`.  Another workaround, not fun but hey, at least your laptop is not useless anymore; buy a usb wifi card, thus bypassing the onboard wify card causing issues.  Note that I have no experience which such device so I cannot help you further with this.